# Creating a file on Google Drive using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm currently trying to create a file on Google Drive and everything works great except that when I try to add properties, modify its contentHints it does not work.

```
function createFile(folder) {
    var fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'config',
        'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream'/*'application/json'*/,
        'parents': [
            folder.id
        ],
        'properties': {
            'hola': 'chao'
        },
        'contentHints': {
            'indexableText': 'Hola'
        }
    };

    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata
    });
    request.execute(function(file) {
        return finishConfig();
    });
}
```

Comment: Please share error that appears in your console if there's any.

Comment: Also share the http request/response from the network tab in the devconsole.

Comment: There isnt any error and I get the file as response object but only with the id, mimeType and name properties